# How do I share a printer from a Windows computer connected to a wireless router?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have three PCs running Windows 7. One has the wireless router connected to it and the printer is connected to that PC. On the other two PCs I installed a NETGEAR N150 Wireless USB Adapter.

How can I connect these PCs so I can print from PC 2 to the printer connected on PC 1?

Comment: If all the machines are on the same network then they all should be able to see the printer (assuming it's a network or wireless printer) - assuming you've installed the correct printer software on all the machines.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're all Windows 7, the easiest way is to create a [Homegroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-homegroup) for all three PCs and enable printer sharing across the home group.  This will allow the other two computers to see the printer on the main computer and print to it (as long as the PC is powered on).

Comment: Ok sir thank you, i will try and inform you sir.!!

Comment: I like, and use this Homegroup solution.  Add the physical printer the computer of the most important person!

Answer (score 0):

1. If the printer is connected directly to the router (via ethernet cable), it should have an IP address. To make the printer visible to the other PCs you need to add it as network printer:

   - Open printers.
   - Click on add printer.
   - Select add network/wireless/bluetooth
   - It should either appear in the box or you can manually set its parameters. Be sure to have the printer drivers at hand if the OS requires them.
2. If the printer is connected directly to the PC and then the PC is connected to the router, you will need to share the printer in the PC and then have the PC on to be able to use the printer by the other PCs.

Comment: If it's a wireless printer it should also be visible as a network printer.

Comment: Sir the printer is connected with the PC and the PC is connected to the router.!! The other two PC's have "NETGEAR N150 WIRELESS USB ADAPTER" sir.!!

Comment: @Sriram Then the second option will work as long as the first PC is powered on.